# Unity cannot select Android SDK even with the correct path

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, sdk

I am currently trying to build an android application with a target for `android 8.0 (daydream vr app)`. I've tried several methods to get Unity to recognize my `Android SDK` I've installed. I even installed SDK version `25.2.5` because other solutions online say this is usually the fix. Since that didn't work I uninstalled the latest `java JDK` and installed `Java 8` since this was shown to be more reliable on forums. Again, no solution to my issue. I keep trying to select the correct path of my SDK and I get the following **error**;

> "Unable to detect SDK in the selected directory":

This is my ERROR MESSAGE

[image]

I select the correct SDK folder and I still receive this, ***how can Unity not detect that this is the SDK?*** Further I've already tried changing the build system from internal to `gradle`, there was no difference. I've been at this for hours now.

Selecting Correct Path

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar bug and I wasn't able to fix it properly. What I did I've downloaded the SDK manually (not from the sdk manager) and it worked for me. Hope you fix it as well. :)

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov, I did that as well, unfortunately I am receiving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- delete "tools" folder in your "sdk" folder
- rename "toolsxxx" folder to "tools"

I believe your only issue was using newer than JDK 8. That is still a requirement, so keep JDK 8 (important: remove any other JDK versions).

The tools downgrade you did appears to no longer be necessary for Unity 2018 (the r25 download workaround). So restoring the folder should help.  With Unity 2018, it appears that we can currently use the latest SDK Build-Tools, SDK Platform-Tools, and SDK Tools right from Android Studio's SDK Manager UI.

Hope it helps, I had the same issue and after uninstalling/reinstalling everything on PC and getting it working, I noticed the only difference on my Mac was that toolsxxx folder.  Worked when I renamed, and noticed your screenshot.